# Mongodb query to select less than and equal based on custom comparator

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am using mongodb database and I need to run less than and equal filter based on custom comparator. Following is more details.

1. "profile" collection is having "level" field as string

   ```
   {"name":"Test1", "level":"intermediate"}
   ```
2. Following are value of level and its corresponding weight

   1. novice
   2. intermediate
   3. experienced
   4. advance
3. I want to write query like as below  so that it should return all the profile collection which level less than and equal to "experienced" (i.e. includes result for "novice", "intermediate" and "experienced"

   ```
   db.profile.find( { level: { $lte: "experienced" } } )
   ```

I understand, I need to provide custom comparator. But how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use custom comparators in a MongoDB Query. The ones available are: [`$eq`, `$gt`, `$gte`, `$lt`, `$lte`, `$ne`, `$in`, `$nin`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/).

You can, however, use `$in` to get what you want:

```
db.profile.find( { level: { $in: [ "experienced", "intermediate ", "novice" ] } } );
```

Comment: Thanks..I think i can build my query to create value for $in :)